# One-To-Many Relationship in Django and QuerySets

Tags: python, django

I have a one-to-many relationship between restaurants and photos. I am having trouble displaying a single image for a corresponding restaurant.

Right now I get all of the restaurants like this:

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all()
```

In my template I have a loop that goes through the restaurants and displays information. However, I am unsure how to retrieve an image that is associated with the restaurant:

```
{% for restaurant in restaurants %}
  {{restaurant.name}}
  {{restaurant.address}}
  {{CODE TO DISPLAY IMAGE}}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

How can I retrieve the first image corresponding to the restaurant? I have tried `restaurant.restaurantphoto_set.get.image`, but this only works when there is a single image.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to diagnose without knowing what your model looks like, but have you tried:

```
restaurant.restaurantphoto_set.all()
```

The docs have some pretty solid examples here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: this is how you would access them in the view.py, not the template.

Comment: @warath-coder it's the name of the method - just a different syntax when you call it in a template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#all

Comment: I know @MarkM just making sure others who read it are aware you can't use that in a template.

Answer (score 1):

do in your template

```
{% for photo in restaurant.restaurantphoto_set.all %}
  {{ photo.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok, but the images have to match the restaurant. So it should have the restaurant name beside the restaurant photo for all of the restaurants.

Comment: this will add all images; add whatever formatting you want around it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving my problem:

```
{% for restaurant in restaurants %}

  {{restaurant.name}}
  {{restaurant.address}}

  {% for photo in restaurant.restaurantphoto_set.all %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %} 
      <img src= "{% static photo.image %}" class="img-curved"> 
    {% endif %} 
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you want to just use the first and only the first image? you don't need the for loop. `restaurant.restaurantphoto_set.all.0` may work

Comment: `restaurant.restaurantphoto_set.all.0.image` really

Comment: Ok, thank you for a cleaner solution. I will try this when I get the chance.